# how do I filter my results

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, filtering

Hi I'm not sure how to filter my results from a Microsoft sql database I have 10 companies with their details including how far they are away from a certain location I just wanted to know how to show only the results within a 100 miles would I do this within my php or sql and how would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM companies WHERE distance <= 100` could work, although you would need to change the companies and distance variables to match your table.

You should check out the [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause a bit more.

Comment: yee in the end i needed to use a WHERE function sql is alot more complicated than i first imagined my end code looked like this: 

     `SELECT *,[tdStoreLocator].[odbcadmin].[fn_calDist]     (-0.03715491813985, 
             0.9178158214586024, 
             long * 0.0174532925, 
             lat * 0.0174532925) as distances 
FROM Customer
WHERE [tdStoreLocator].[odbcadmin].[fn_calDist](-0.03715491813985, 
             0.9178158214586024, 
             long * 0.0174532925, 
             lat * 0.0174532925) <=115;`

Comment: SQL can get pretty darn complicated indeed! It's also really powerful.

Comment: yeee i know just pain in the ass when you have only been learning it 10 hours